# API/library/tool to validate JS code?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some stuff done in PHP, and now I need to validate (just syntax validation) if the user is writing a valid JS in one of my form fields. What options I have apart of JSLint?

Comment: What type of validating you need? Syntax check, code quality, coding style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check syntax you can use javascript parsers e.g. Esprima parser (http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) or Acorn.js (https://github.com/marijnh/acorn). Also there is pure php implementation - jParser - http://apps.timwhitlock.info/jparser/index.html